# How to copy the last N rows of data?

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have VBA code which 'mirrors'/copies a specific range of cells from another workbook/sheet. The range of cells are row after row of test results.

Is there a way to copy the last 10 (or however many) rows of data, instead of a specific range?

```vb
Set Dat1 = Workbooks("Test Results.xlsm").Worksheets("Example").Range("AP31:AP15000") 

Raw1.Range("A3:A15000").Resize(Dat1.Rows.Count, Dat1.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = Dat1.Cells.Value
```

**The first line of code sets Dat1 as the data AP31:AP15000 from the test result file.**

**The second line is basically saying put the value of Dat1 into Raw1 (which is my destination).**

Can I use this method for say selecting the last 20 rows or do I have to use a different method?

Comment: You could try to find the last used row and resize 10 positions up from that cell.

Comment: `Range("AP31:AP15000").Rows(Range("AP31:AP15000").Rows.Count - 10 & ":" & Range("AP31:AP15000").Rows.Count)`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Thanks I will give this a go...

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Will it still work even though AP15000 is not the last row of data? IE in normal conditions we wont know if the last row of data?? (maybe should have mentioned that in my question)